# Redirect users via PHP depending on selected Id

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, redirect

I have selecting data from *MySQL* table and returned data looks like:

```
Name    Rank    Vessel Type    Preview
John    1       ab             View
Lisa    1       cd             View
Carl    2       bd             View
```

As you see above `View` should be link to user's profiles depending on their `Id`.

For now I'm using table as you see below and this is line for `View` link:

`<?php echo "<td> <a href='preview.php?Id='" . $Id . ">View</a></td>"; ?>`

I don't know why, but It redirecting users like: `www.etc.com/preview.php?Id=` without provided Id.

If I'm using something like:

`<?php echo "<td> <a href='preview.php?Id='" . $Id . ">View " . $Id . "</a></td>"; ?>`

It returning `View Id` for example `View 1`, that's mean `$Id` variable is fine. Have you ideas what's wrong?

Also I want to ask you If it is correct way for redirecting? Or there is any other / better way to do that?

This is **PHP**:

```
<?php
if(isset($UserID)) {    

    $users = $con->prepare("
    SELECT DISTINCT Id, 
                    CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) AS FullName, 
                    RankApplied, 
                    VesselsType 
    FROM tbl
"); 
    $users->execute();

    $users->bind_result($Id, $FName, $RankApplied, $VesselsType);


} else {
    echo "There is no User ID detected, try to refresh browser.";   
}
?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Rank</th>       
        <th>Vessel Type</th>
        <th>Preview</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    while ($users->fetch()) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $FName; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $RankApplied; ?></td>        
        <td><?php echo $VesselsType; ?></td>
        <?php echo "<td> <a href='preview.php?Id='" . $Id . ">View</a></td>"; ?> 
    </tr>
    <?php 
    } 
    ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
<?php echo "<td> <a href='preview.php?Id='" . $Id . ">View</a></td>"; ?>
```

with

```
<?php echo "<td> <a href='preview.php?Id=" . $Id . ">View</a></td>"; ?>
```

You are having a `'` after `?Id=` which was creating the problem..

Instead of concatenating the `$ID` you could directly use

```
<?php echo "<td> <a href='preview.php?Id=$Id'>View</a></td>"; ?>
```

As in the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

> Double quote strings will display a host of escaped characters
>   (including some regexes), and variables in the strings will be
>   evaluated. An important point here is that you can use curly braces to
>   isolate the name of the variable you want evaluated. For example let's
>   say you have the variable $type and you what to echo "The $types are"
>   That will look for the variable $types. To get around this use echo
>   "The {$type}s are" You can put the left brace before or after the
>   dollar sign. Take a look at string parsing to see how to use array
>   variables and such

Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3446286/3168859)

Comment: Thank you, that worked. 1 more question, in preview.php should I use `$_GET` to catch sent Id?

Comment: Yes..you could use $_GET['Id'] to get the query string

Comment: Your answer will either not echo anything or cause a parse error. I suggest you go over it again. The other answer below given by Richard is what should have been used here.

Comment: Test it yourself and you will see. That alone will be "self-explanatory" ;-)

Comment: @Infinity how could that have possibly worked? I tested Lal's code and either didn't echo anything, or produced invalid HTML, or caused a parse error here `<?php echo "<td> <a href='preview.php?Id=$Id">View</a></td>"; ?>`. Edit: You deleted your comment about it working.

Comment: The `<?php echo "<td> <a href='preview.php?Id=$Id">View</a></td>"; ?>` (`parse error, unexpected '<'...` should have been `<?php echo "<td> <a href='preview.php?Id=$Id'>View</a></td>"; ?>` here.

Comment: I'm using like this: `<?php echo "<td> <a href='preview.php?Id=$Id'">View</a></td>"; ?>` seems like Lal missed `'`, but I like idea to avoid concatenating.

Comment: Updated the answer @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Infinity `<?php echo "<td> <a href='preview.php?Id=$Id">View</a></td>"; ?>` that will throw a parse error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in...` http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes, sure, that because Lal missed `'`, but this is not problem :) I didn't noticed at all It, just used his idea to use $Id directly.

Comment: There is something I am definitely NOT getting here gentlemen. `<?php echo "<td> <a href='preview.php?Id=$Id'">View</a></td>"; ?>` will throw `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'`

Comment: @Fred-ii- ahh really, don't need to use `"`. This is from my code and working: `<?php echo "<td> <a href='preview.php?Id=$Id'>View</a></td>"; ?> `

Comment: @Infinity I fixed Lal's syntax error. Lal, that downvote is not mine. Actually, I just upvoted it ;-)

Comment: Thankyou @Infinity ... :)

Comment: Uff @Fred-ii- ...that was really a mistake..sorry...and thanks for the great support..:)

Answer (score 3):

You are closing your `href` quote before including the id, change the line to the following to get it to work:

```
<?php echo "<td> <a href='preview.php?Id=" . $Id . "'>View</a></td>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solving your problem:**

```
<?php echo "<td> <a href='preview.php?Id=".$Id . "'>View</a></td>"; ?>
```

**Alternatively you may define before using it:**

```
<?php $link = "preview.php?Id=$Id"; ?>
<?php echo "<a href='$link'>View</a>"; ?>
```

**Also you may try PHP in HTML**

```
<a href='<?php echo "preview.php?Id=$Id"?>'>View</a>
```